# 2010 Ford E250: the wrench icon came on and van shut off

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, van

After shut down, I wait 10 seconds, then it starts and runs fine. First time this happened.

How can I figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome, thank you for contributing a question. This may be a hard question to answer without more detail. Keep an eye out for comments as people may be asking for more information. Meanwhile it would make sense to read the codes (or get them read) they will likely hold clues to what is going on.

Comment: As @dlu states, [what are the codes](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/4152)?

Comment: After you "wait 10 seconds" does the wrench icon go away?

Comment: on fords the wrench icon can indicate problems/codes setting in the transmission computer. when does it stall? when coming to a stop? while your driving? when you're taking off from a stop? is there a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's time to visit a mechanic or dealer with an OBD-II reader (or get one yourself - can even get a bluetooth model and see the results on your smartphone) and see what the onboard computer is trying to tell you.